Maximum Sum of Products NP Complete
I'm working on the following problem:

You have a multiset of $3N$ nonnegative real numbers $S$.

You must partition this set into $N$ triples.

The goal is to maximize the sum of the products of each of the
triples.

The decision version is if the max sum of products can reach a threshold $k$.


For example, the set $\{0, 0.5, 1, 1,1,1\}$ can be divided into
$(0, 0.5, 1), \space  (1,1,1)$
For a sum of products of $0+1=1$.
I'm convinced that this problem is NP-Complete, as it is obviously in $NP$ and there are an non polynomial number of possible partitions.
But I'm struggling to prove it is NP-Hard, I've been trying to reduce from 3-partition, but I'm struggling to encode how to make it so that if and only if each of the triples in the original problem can sum to the same value, can the sum of products reach a certain threshold.
I'm also most interested in the case where these values are between 0 and 1.
3D matching and 3-Partition seem like the most natural reductions, but I am finding they are still not very straightforward, and the proof of 3-partition itself is not very intuitive, so I am pretty stuck.
Any guidance towards a working reduction would be appreciated.

If you allow arbitrary computable numbers, then the computational complexity can be arbitrarily difficult (as we can produce computable numbers which are extremely difficult to compute) so it wouldn't even be NP. I assume you want to restrict your numbers to be rational. The version of this problem restricted to rationals is equivalent to the version restricted to integers, by multiplying through by a common denominator. Each partition has its sum of products multiplied by $D^3$, which doesn't change the relative rankings of partitions.

You can assume the numbers to be rational or integers. Calculating the product of any one triple of numbers can be assumed to be constant. Do you have any ideas for the NP-Hardness reduction?

This problem can be solved in polynomial time, so it's not NP hard (unless P=NP). The optimal solution is to place the three largest numbers together in a triplet, and repeat with the next largest three in the next triplet, and so on. Solving the problem is as easy as sorting the multiset, so the complexity should be $\mathcal{O}(N\log(N))$ at most.

I'll start by proving my claim in the case $N=2$, where we have $6$ numbers, and the general case will follow by induction. Let's say $a,b,c$ are the three largest numbers, and $x,y,z$ are the smaller three numbers. Since there's only two parts, it must be the case that at least two of the larger numbers are already within the same part. If not all three, then the only alternative would be something like $abz+xyc$. To show that $abc+xyz$ is larger, just take the difference.
$$\begin{align}
(abc+xyz) - (abz+xyc) &= (abc-abz) - (xyc-xyz) \\
&= ab(c-z) - xy(c-z) \\
&= (ab-xy)(c-z)
\end{align}$$
Since we presume that each of $a,b,c$ are larger than each of $x,y,z$, it's necessarily the case that $ab\geq xy$ and $c\geq z$, therefore the above difference is non-negative. It follows that $abc+xyz$ is the largest possible sum of products, proving my claim in the case $N=2$.

To prove my claim in general, we can just use the $N=2$ case in an induction. Let $a,b,c$ be the three largest numbers in our multiset, and if $a,b$ are not in the same partition, then we have a subset of our partition taking the form $(a,x,y),(b,n,k)$. This subset can be made better by rearranging those six numbers such that $b$ is paired with $a$. This proves the two largest numbers must be paired together. If the third largest number $c$ weren't also paired with them, we could repeat the same technique to get a better partition, so all three of $a,b,c$ must be paired together.
The above argument proves that the ideal partition always pairs the largest three numbers together. This partition is optimized by optimizing the remaining multiset, and inductively it follows that the ideal solution is to just sort the multiset and construct the triplets in-place from that.

This probably generalizes to cases where we use quadruplets instead of triplets, and so on. There's probably an easier way to get the generalization by analyzing the case where we partition into pairs.

Ah I can see that now. Thank you.
The question that started me down this path is this:

3N Bernoulli random variables
Partition into N groups
A group "passes" if at least 2 of its variables are 1
Maximize the expected number of groups that pass.
The greedy algorithm above obviously doesn't work for this. I am more confident that this problem is NP-Complete, but have been unable to prove it still.
The decision version would be "are at least $k$ groups expected to pass?"


@zjxs That sounds like a completely different problem, honestly. If you think my answer satisfies the question you posted, you should accept it and post a new question about this different problem. That way you'll get more relevant answers. It's hard to tell without you elaborating on the details, but this alternate question you mention sounds like a straightforward probability problem, and I don't think it'll be NP hard either. It sounds like the optimal solution will be a binomial distribution with a mean being $3N/4$ groups passing in the optimal partition.
